# Jwt token unable to generate

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to generate a JWT Token in laravel. I am using Tymon. I am working in laravel 5.8 and I need to copy most of the stuff from 5.4 version.

This is what so far I have tried.

### Controller

```
$payload = (object)array("userid" => $user->userid);
$extra = [
      "userid" => $user->userid,
      "username" => $user->username,
      "useremail" => $user->useremail
   ];

$return = JWTAuth::fromUser($payload, $extra);
```

### User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I am trying this using postman where I am getting this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT::fromUser() must be an instance of Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject, instance of stdClass given, called in
```

Comment: Have you even read the error message?

Answer (score 2):

To Use JWT Auth in Laravel you must follow these steps -

1. Install in Composer.json via:

`composer require tymon/jwt-auth`

2. Add the service provider to the providers array in the config/app.php config 
   file as follows:

```
'providers' => [

    ...

    Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class,
]
```

3. Run the following command to publish the package config file:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

You should now have a config/jwt.php file that allows you to configure the basics of this package.

4. Generate the secret Key via this command:

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```

this should update your .env file with something like:

```
JWT_SECRET=foobar
```

5. Then Update the User model as:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    // Rest omitted for brevity

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

6. finally, configure the Auth guard  in `config/auth.php` as:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

...

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Then You are ready to go..

Comment: Yes this is what I am following

Comment: thank you thats great answer. all that we config them later but if laravel can have wizard for them like composer i we can develop it faster

Comment: sure, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you are passing a stdClass instance where JWTSubject instance is expected as the first parameter of the JWTAuth::fromUser method.

Have a look at this issue: [github issue](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/260)

The developers suggest to either pass User model or implementation of Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject interface